# Add two methods to the same event in the observer

Tags: event-observer, methods

Hi I need help with the following

I created a new method in for `sales/model/observer.php` as follows

```
class Company_Sales_Model_Observer
{

    public function addid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
       <code to write in the log file>
    }
}
```

There is already another method registered in the config.xml file as follows

```
   <events>
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <company_sales>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_sales/observer</class>
                    <method>processEbook</method>
                </company_sales>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
    </events>
```

I added the following code in the sales/etc/config.xml after the existing method registration as follows

```
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <company_sales>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_sales/observer</class>
                    <method>processEbook</method>
                </company_sales>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <company_sales>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_sales/observer</class>
                    <method>addid</method>
                </company_sales>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
```

But it is not calling the method. Where am I going wrong? Please help

Thanks!

Update: What if I want to create the method addid with the event sales_order_save_commit_after as the method ProcessEbook. How will I go about it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: just change the event name you have use company_sales  two time just put unique name for each events

Comment: also put config.xml on this question

Comment: for second  sales_order_save_commit_after event change company_sales to other name

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your config.xml file you will find duplicate observer tag names . These names must be unique, otherwise magento will only the first one it finds. Please change it to something unique. A good approach is to use namespace in your tag names.
Thanks.

You can do it in the following way,

```
<sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <company_sales>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_sales/observer</class>
                    <method>processEbook</method>
                </company_sales>
                <company_sales_addid>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>company_sales/observer</class>
                    <method>addid</method>
                </company_sales_addid>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
```

Please notice the tag `<company_sales_addid>`. The name of this tag must be unique. Otherwise it won't work.

Thanks.